# Why bottom Anchor ad is not showing all the time in AdSense auto ads?

Tags: adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

I have checked that the bottom Anchor ad provided by Adsense is not showing all the time. It is only showing almost 50% of my visitors. That's why my earning is dropping. I have using Adsense auto ads on my websites -

1. https://www.sarojmeher.com/seotools/
2. https://www.sarojmeher.com/tools/
3. https://www.sarojmeher.com/blog/

Comment: Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then edit your question. Show what you got, what you aim for, and what you get and make clear what your problem is.

Comment: AdSense doesn't guarantee 100% ad fill rate. So 50% fill rate maybe normal. Also consider using top anchor instead as bottom anchor have limited pool of ads that can be shown there due to certain click-protection restrictions. Top anchors don't have that restriction.